# Part of speech of "Much"

Tags: parts-of-speech

(1)

> I don't care too much about it.

In this sentence, 'much' is a 'pronoun' or an 'adverb'?

(2)

> A situation or action is too much for you

In this sentence, 'much' is a 'pronoun' or an 'adjective'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't care too much about it.

*Too much* answers the question "how X do I care?"  "How" questions are adverbs (they qualify the sense of a verb).

> A situation or action is too much for you

*Much* is a pronoun here.  *To be* is a copular verb that can act as an "equal sign" for two nouns.  Pronouns are able to take the place of nouns *or* stand in for where a noun would go but doesn't appear because the idea is indefinite.

*Much* is never an adjective.  If you want to say there's a large amount of X, and X is a noun, use *many* instead.

> There was much disappointment today.
>
> There were many disappointing events today.

---

You're right, *much* can be a determiner.  Most determiners that don't also act as pronouns are never on the far end of a copular verb.  For possessive pronouns (really determiners), there's special words for example.

> This is my box.
>
> This box is mine (if you said *this box is my* the listener/speaker will think the sentence is unfinished).

But if the determiner can also be a pronoun, then it's fine to put it after *to be* or other copular verb.

> My box is this (works because *this* works as a determiner and pronoun).
>
> There is much chaos.
>
> The chaos is much.

It's far more common to use a qualifier like *too* or *very* with much after *to be* or other copular verb, but a plain *much* isn't wrong.  It will sound a little jarring and is less common than using a qualifier with *much*.

> The chaos is too much.
>
> It seems a bit much.
>
> The perfume doesn't smell very much.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Now, I have understood that 'much' in (1) is an adverb. As to (2), I know that the term 'determiner' is more appropriate than 'adjective'. But how about this? learnersdictionary.com/definition/much According to this dictionary, we can use the term 'adjective', and 'Much' can be an adjective. Is this wrong? And I know that a copular verb can take a noun or an adjective. Do all of these not affect the idea that in (2), 'much' is a pronoun? For caution's sake, I don't intend to refute your reply. I'm just trying to make sure.

Comment: Good point.  I updated my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed reply. 
After all, you mean that in (1), 'much' is an adverb and in (2), 'much' is a noun.

Comment: What is this nonsense about "The chaos is much" being better than "There is much chaos?" As a native speaker (US), the latter sentence is much better than the former. And while "There was much disappointment today" is undoubtedly bad, it's no worse than "There was disappointment today;" that is, the problem with that sentence is not the use of the word "much."